# Elasticsearch script query array field size comparison

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to make a comparison with respect to the length of an array field in Elasticsearch?

For instance the following works (sourceId is a text type field)

```
GET /entity_active/_count
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "doc['sourceId'].values.size() > 0",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the following does not work (users is an array field)

```
GET /entity_active/_count
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "doc['users'].values.size() > 0",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The latter returns such a response:

```
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
 "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:80)",
              "doc['users'].values.size() > 0",
          "    ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "doc['users'].values.size() > 0",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
```

Do I need to use an alternative way to make use of such array fields?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not indexed in ES, hence you cannot access an array via doc_values (i.e. through `doc.`). You can access the `_source` document in which the array is present, though, using `ctx._source`. Try this script instead:

```
_source.users.size() > 0
```

or

```
_source.users.length > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Val however I still have this error. I tried the following revised query block: GET /mail_active/_count
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "ctx._source.users.size() > 0",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} and I get the following error:
      "reason": "runtime error",
      "script_stack": [
          "ctx._source.users.size() > 0",
          "   ^---- HERE"

Comment: Which version of ES are you running? Try to remove `ctx`, I've updated my answer.

Comment: We're using verison 5.1. I removed cts without any luck :( "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "compile error",
        "script_stack": [
          "_source.users.size() > 0",
          "^---- HERE"

Comment: compile_error seems to indicate a different issue. Can you try with `length` instead of `size()`?

Comment: Once again, the same error with length. Am I doing something wrong here? Here's my request: `GET /mail_active/_count
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "_source.users.length > 0",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Can you try with `groovy` instead of `painless`?

Comment: I get many of the following with **groovy**: `type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"script\" : {\n          \"script\" : {\n            \"inline\" : \"_source.users.length > 0\",\n            \"lang\" : \"groovy\"\n          },\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"disable_coord\" : false,\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
        "index_uuid": "ElifktuqRZWGVM5IfTawtA",
        "index": "entity_180112"
      },`